# How to fire Async TransactionalEventListener in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, eclipselink

I want to do some stuff after `TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION` but in `Async` mode. Problem is in current implementation it runs in sync mode how can i make it `Async`?

> @TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMPLETION)

Comment: Put `@Async` on the method and make sure you have `@EnableAsync` in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Async(springframework.scheduling.annotation) annotation on the same method.